# Counting zeros in an array assembly 8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

I wrote this code to count the number of zeros in the array vec:

```
.model small
.stack 100h           
.data
    vec dw 1,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,0,0,5
    m1 dw 0
.code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov di,1 ;di is our running index
number_of_zeros:
    mov ax,vec[di]
    cmp ax,0
    je increment_m1 ;case its zero
    inc di;case its not zero
    cmp di,11
    jl number_of_zeros
    cmp di,11
    je end
increment_m1:
    inc m1
    inc di
    cmp di,11
    jl number_of_zeros
    cmp di,11
    je end
end:
    mov ax,m1
```

It's not displaying the correct output. I'm expecting to see AX=4, but instead, when the program finished running I can see that AX=3.

I think the problem is with how I access individual elements in the array. For some reason that I can't figure out, at the first iteration it says that vec[1]=0200

Edit: Ok I correct the code, it does indeed give the desired outcome BUT...It still shows weird values for vec[di]. I still think I'm accessing it wrong and i got the correct result because of chance. I'd like someone to review it.

Comment: Just to be clear on what I'm asking, the first time the program reaches the line mov ax,vec[di] I expect it to mov 1. but instead it moves 0200.

Comment: I notice that you initialize your di register to 1 rather than 0. It's been a very very long time since I wrote 8086 assembly code, but isn't the memory addressing in the 8086 at single byte resolution. I could be completely wrong, but if that is the case then you should be incrementing di by 2 after reading each dw from vec.

Answer (score 4):

There are three problems, and many ways of improving your solution, I'll just mention the fixes:

1. the first element of the array is at offset `0`, not `1`
2. each element has a size of `2`, not `1`
3. the comparison for the end condition needs to be updated (for reasons 1 and 2)

So this line

```
mov di,1 ;di is our running index
```

Should be

```
mov di,0 ;di is our running index
```

and this line

```
inc di;case its not zero
```

should be

```
add di,2 ;case its not zero
```

and this line

```
cmp di,11
```

should be

```
cmp di,20 ; last element is at offset sizeof(dw) * (num_elements-1) = 2 * (11-1) = 20
```

That should get it working.

Comment: I just realized that i need to increment by 2 and not by 1, that indeed solves the problem, thank you for your input.

Comment: I also wrote mov di,offset vec, and then mov ax,[di] instead. seems to do the same thing.